# Dynamic High Chart no Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to plot high chart from the example given in the HighChart Web Site.

The code I am trying is given below,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Chart
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });

            // Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
                chart: {
                    events: {
                        load: function () {

                            // set up the updating of the chart each second
                            var series = this.series[0];
                            setInterval(function () {
                                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                            }, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                },

                rangeSelector: {
                    buttons: [{
                        count: 1,
                        type: 'minute',
                        text: '1M'
                    }, {
                        count: 5,
                        type: 'minute',
                        text: '5M'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
                    inputEnabled: false,
                    selected: 0
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Live random data'
                },

                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Random data',
                    data: (function () {
                        // generate an array of random data
                        var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                        for (i = -999; i <= 0; i++) {
                            data.push([
                                time + i * 1000,
                                Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                            ]);
                        }
                        return data;
                    })()
                }]
            });

        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately nothing is coming up in the google chrome.

Error Code : `0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: This is the start http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/8Q4NL/

Comment: Well, for me your code works perfectly fine.. when you open javascript console, do you have any errors there?

Comment: it works fine in jsfiddle but why it is not coming up in chrome?

Comment: Well I found the error please see the updated code

Comment: You forget to add which method is not supported.. ;) That error means you are including twice some library (like jQuery) or order of files is wrong. Are you sure you have included proper code? Also, add doctype to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some mistake in referencing the jquery files. I made it in order and its working perfectly fine..

Chart

```
      <!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/exporting.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> !-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });

            // Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
                chart: {
                    events: {
                        load: function () {

                            // set up the updating of the chart each second
                            var series = this.series[0];
                            setInterval(function () {
                                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                            }, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                },

                rangeSelector: {
                    buttons: [{
                        count: 1,
                        type: 'minute',
                        text: '1M'
                    }, {
                        count: 5,
                        type: 'minute',
                        text: '5M'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
                    inputEnabled: false,
                    selected: 0
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Live random data'
                },

                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Random data',
                    data: (function () {
                        // generate an array of random data
                        var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                        for (i = -999; i <= 0; i++) {
                            data.push([
                                time + i * 1000,
                                Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                            ]);
                        }
                        return data;
                    })()
                }]
            });

        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A small example on highcharts

```
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
 <button id="update">Update chart</button>


$(function () {
var cat=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        animation: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: cat
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});

i = 1;
$('#update').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].data[0].update(i++ % 2 ? 200 : 0);
});
});
```